# Creating a generic package for dataload to crm

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, kingswaysoft

I am trying to create a generic ssis package using kingswaysoft and script task in ssis where I am passing  lists of tables and getting the schema of the table from database in the script task now I want this schema output to be accessible in the dataflow in ssis is it possible or not 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, my organization uses the same method you described to load CRM datasets - even using Kingswaysoft products to assist with the data load.

At the core of this, you'll need to use a Dynamics CRM source task with an XML script to query your data. From there you can load it into a SQL Server or treat it as you would any other kind of flowing data.

I noticed you've tagged this question with [C#]. For something like this, no C# is necessary when using the Kingswaysoft Data Flow tasks.

[image]